# Como enviar un formulario en REACT JS

Tags: javascript, formularios, reactjs

Buenas tardes mi pregunta es por lo sieguiente, yo en mis formularios suelo enviar los inputs a traves de `refs` sin embargo en la documentacion utiliza el state del mismo componente para tomar los valores es decir algo como esto:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
...
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

La pregunta es cual es la mejor forma de hacer esto ya que en la documentacion en donde habla sobre componentes no controlados menciona que se recomiendan este tipo de componentes para formularios y ahi si lo pasan por refs, y adicionalmente si es la unica forma de hacerlo ya que por egemplo en Angular hay forma de enviar todo el formulario completo y no input por input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general el uso de refs [es desaconsejado](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), ya que eventualmente tendrás un lío referenciando elementos de un lado para otro (al menos eso me he encontrado en algún proyecto y de verdad que es un caos).
Para lo que mencionas, creo que es mejor recibir los valores a través del event, aunque si tu proyecto eventualmente va a crecer, podrías considerar usar un state manager como [redux](https://es.redux.js.org/) junto con [redux-form](https://redux-form.com) para el manejo de inputs en un formulario.